# Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause error

Tags: mysql

Can some help me to solve this query

```
UPDATE
    LoadBal_WebAPI_RequestDetails
SET
    status='vamsi'
WHERE
    requestID in (select `lb`.`requestId` AS `requestID` from (`LoadBal_WebAPI_RequestDetails` `lb` join `Global_AR_Processes` `ar` on((`ar`.`processId` = `lb`.`processRegistryId`))) where ((`lb`.`status` = 'Received') and (`ar`.`isProcessAvailable` = 1)) order by `lb`.`lastUpdatedDateTime` )
    LIMIT 1;
```

I am getting error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

I am new in query writing, so suggest me in solving the error

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
UPDATE
    LoadBal_WebAPI_RequestDetails
SET
    status='vamsi'
WHERE
    requestID in (select t1.requestID FROM 
    (select requestId, processRegistryId from LoadBal_WebAPI_RequestDetails where `status` = 'Received' order by `lastUpdatedDateTime`) t1 JOIN
    `Global_AR_Processes` `ar` on `ar`.`processId` = t1.processRegistryId and `ar`.`isProcessAvailable` = 1)
    LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use nested table as select from your select statement like this

*UPDATE tbl SET col = (
  **SELECT ... FROM (SELECT.... FROM) AS x**);*